# Start mongo 3 on wiredTiger right after installation

Tags: mongodb

When I install mongodb 3 on a fresh Ubuntu box (following the official documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), the mongod service starts automatically (right after installation) on mmapv1.

I then have to:
- stop the service
- copy a new configuration file to /etc/mongod.conf so it uses wiredTiger
- restart the service

Is there a way to have the mongod start on wiredTiger right after the installation ?

Comment: I do not believe so but it should be easy enough to make any install script for your servers do this process automatically

Comment: I'm using Ansible to do this automatically, that is working fine but I'd rather like the service does not start so I can setup the configuration file and run mongod right after.